# OAuth2 requestMatchers for actuator permitAll not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I successfully upgraded several Spring Boot apps from Spring 5.x to 6.x with Java 17.

But I struggle with a serie of apps with OAuth2 authentication. Actually every thing works as expected accept the actuator URL without security. I would expect this to work:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt()
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter());
    return http.build();
}
```

But I get an 401 when I call `http://localhost:8080/actuator/info`.

With Spring Boot 2.7.5 this worked fine with the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .cors(withDefaults())
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
             authorizeRequests
                 .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/actuator").permitAll()
                 .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/actuator/health").permitAll()
                 .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/actuator/info").permitAll()
                 .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt()
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter());
}
```

It looks like with Spring Boot 3 and OAuth2 security you can't open some URLs anymore.

Any idea?

Comment: Yes you can permitAll with boot 3 and OAuth2 resource server (I do). Your CORS conf seems to have changed a bit. Can you tell us more about your test request: user agent, exact URI, authentication configuration, console output (on both sides with DEBUG level for spring security)? For instance, providing with an invalid authentication will result in 401 even on an endpoint accepting anonymous.

Comment: Did you annotate your class with `@Configuration`? Did you send a wrong JWT? You should provide Spring Security DEBUG logs. It will help to find your problem. Therefore change your log configuration.

Comment: ```@Configuration``` was missing! I had ```@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity``` and ```@EnableWebSecurity``` before but removed ```@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity``` because it is deprecated. So I guess ```@Configuration``` was in there. Thanks for the help!